# Unable to install Chrome extension through command-line on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, installation

I'm trying to install Chrome extension through command-line to the Google Chrome on Mac OS X:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --install-from-webstore=extension_id
```

Google Chrome causes a crash

This operations was successfully on Windows:

```
chrome.exe --install-from-webstore=extension_id
```

Comment: This bug has been reported in May already, see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=238099

Comment: I've asked the People In Charge to have a look at the bug.

Comment: Thanks. I will be know